# How to Access remote VM over/ With VPN

Tags: virtual-machine, openvpn

I am new to this. I have few remote machines and I want to access them securely only via VPN how to do I achieve this? I want to build this from scratch. I was trying to work with pritunl.

Comment: I am not sure why you would build this from scratch. I have a solid VPN router and I can access my home computer and all the apps (including Virtual Machines) from anywhere I happen to be. I just used available building blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The way we usually set this up is to enable RDP access to the VM. But instead of opening the port 3389 in the router we setup a VPN server inside the network of the VM instead. This can be done on the same router if the router has VPN support.

To connect, Make a VPN connection to the network first, then start Microsoft Remote Desktop and connect to the local ip of the VM over port 3389.

Comment: +1. That is a good way to go.

Comment: How to do if the remote machine is managed by some other provider and i only have access to remote machine via its public ip?

Comment: Use whatever tool you have to connect to the remote pc, install a VPN server there and ensure that the right ports are open, then make a VPN connection and test that it works, then use rdp to connect to the local ip address of your VM and once you tested that this works, setup the RDP port to only be allowed on the local ip range and block public ip range in the firewall.